# Method to detect if multi-byte support is required

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

Is there any way in Flex to detect if the user's locale requires multi-byte support to render content? Our app uses an embedded vector font but we have added a toggle to use system fonts if they need multi-byte support.

A request has been made to auto-detect this state. We could look at all the strings and make a guess but I was wondering if Flex provides a mechanism to detect this.